# Slice an array into 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a method which is intended to slice one bigger `Array` into a few smaller arrays. I would like it to return these arrays as an two dimensional array. So far slicing works but I have no idea how to write `arr2[]` elements to `slice[][]`. The problem is count of arrays `slice[?][i]` is unknown.

```
private short[][] slice(short array1[], int sliceSize)    {

    short arr2[]=null;
    short slice[][]=null;

    for (int offset = 0; offset < array1.length ; offset+=sliceSize) {

            arr2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(array1, offset, offset+sliceSize);

            for(int i=0; i<arr2.length; i++)    {
                System.out.print("\n value: "+ String.valueOf(arr2[i]));
                // slice[?][i]=arr2[i];
            }
        }

    return slice;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily know the number of slice you need from the orignal array length.

```
int sliceCount = arr1.length / sliceSize + 1; 
short[][] slice = new short[sliceCount][];
```

*Note that we would end up with one to many cell if the length is a multiple of the slice size, we can simply substract 1 to `arr1.length` to correct that (didn't do it to keep the code simple)*

Then, you just need to do some copy just like you do and store the result in it. 
Since `Arrays.copyOfRange` return a new array instance each call, you can store the instance directly instead of iterating the array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < sliceCount; i++) {
    arr2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(array1, i * sliceSize, ( i + 1 ) * sliceSize);
    slice[i] = arr2;
}
return slice;
```

Example :

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] into slice of 4 length
-> [
      [1,2,3,4],
      [5,6,7,8],
      [9,0,0,0]
   ]
```